# Include poppler while generating an application using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, poppler

I am using poppler to read pdfs

Poppler folder is located with my source file as shown below.
Code below:

```
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file,500,poppler_path = r'.\\poppler\\bin',
                              first_page=pageNo[0],last_page =pageNo[len(pageNo)-1] )
```

I want to generate the exe for my python application using pyinstaller.
However i include them in pyinstaller command.It doesnt seem to work.

I get the below error:
**Exception Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? occurred while creating the DB dataframes**

Below are the ways i have tried to include the poppler in my pyinstaller command:

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data --add-data "C:/Users/projectPath/poppler/*;./poppler"  "C:/Users/projectPath/AutoUpdate.py"

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data --add-data "C:/Users/projectPath/poppler;./poppler"  "C:/Users/projectPath/AutoUpdate.py"

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data --add-data "C:/Users/projectPath/poppler;poppler/"  "C:/Users/projectPath/AutoUpdate.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using onedir approach instead of onefile.Works fine now.

Below is the updated pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data --add-data "C:/Users/projectPath/poppler/*;./poppler" "C:/Users/projectPath/AutoUpdate.py"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's because of `--onefile` option? Changing to `--onedir` does not solve the problem for me.

Comment: What do you have in your `poppler/` directory? Binary file? I installed poppler with `conda install -c conda-forge poppler` and `poppler` located inside Anaconda's env directory.